# Restrict jQuery fadeIn()

Tags: jquery, fadein

The default functionality of the `.fadeIn()`, increases opacity from 0 to 1.

I was just wondering if there is a way to restrict this. (Say) increase the opacity to 0.8 and not more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use: `.fadeTo(time, opacity)`

```
$('#element')fadeTo(900, 0.7);
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/

Answer (score 2):

try `fadeTo()` method:

```
$('#elem').fadeTo('slow', 0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element').fadeTo(1000, 0.8);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/7MnZc/)**

Comment: This is what I currently have, but doesn't work 'coz you can see it going to 1 and coming back to 0.3 (in your case).

Comment: You could use .animate(), but as other people pointed out: .fadeTo() is closer to what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function effect?